# Segmented Control- Change label text in another view

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 views 1) ViewController and 2)ViewController2. 
In the first view controller I have some lablels that when I run the segment controller the names change. All I want to do is, in (Viewcontroller2) where I have a label, I want it to be able to change the text as well based on the segmented controller being 0 or 1. Here is what I have.

```
            //  ViewController.h

             #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
        IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Lang;
        IBOutlet UIButton *Run;
         IBOutlet UILabel *bet;
     }

     -(IBAction)ChangeLang:(id)sender;

    @end
```

Then in the m file i have the following to change the data

```
  //  ViewController.m
  #import "ViewController.h"
  #import "ViewController2.h"

  @interface ViewController ()

 @end

    @implementation ViewController

  -(IBAction)ChangeLang  :(id)sender {  

 if (Lang.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
 {  
    bet.text=@"Apple";
    Run.titleLabel.text=@"Banana";
   //not sure here what code to put in order to make the label in viewcontroller2 change.

 }

 if (Lang.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {

    bet.text=@"ORANGES";
    Run.titleLabel.text=@"FRUITS";
  //not sure here what code to put in order to make the label in viewcontroller2 change.
  }
 }
```

This runs fine... heres what I have in VIEWController 2

```
 //  Viewcontroller2.h
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

 IBOutlet UILabel *Nextword;

@end
```

In the M controller i just have this

```
 #import "ViewController2.h"
  #import "ViewController.h"
  @interface ViewController2 ()


@end
```

How would I, when I run the segmented controller, make the uilabel text change in the ViewController2? Can anyone help? I dont want the screen to go to viewcontroller automatically, I was able to do that. I want the text to change, and then when i swipe to go there, i want the text in Viewcontroller2 to be according to the if statement based on the segmented controller.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an access to instance of `ViewController2` from `ViewController`.

Use this code inside your `ViewController.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Lang;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Run;
    IBOutlet UILabel *bet;

    ViewConstroller2 * VC2;
}

-(IBAction)ChangeLang:(id)sender;

@end
```

When you're creating instance of `ViewController2` store it in `VC2` variable.

Then use this code as your UISegmentedControl change event:

```
 -(IBAction)ChangeLang:(id)sender {  

 if (Lang.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
 {  
    bet.text=@"Apple";
    Run.titleLabel.text=@"Banana";

    VC2.Nextword= "YOUR_WORD";
 }

 if (Lang.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {

    bet.text=@"ORANGES";
    Run.titleLabel.text=@"FRUITS";

    VC2.Nextword= "YOUR_WORD";
  }
 }
```